# With Postgres, calculate, for a set of input date, availability based on three tables and conditional values

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say you have three tables:

```
[default_limit]
id | location | limit

[daily_limit]
date | location | id | limit

[reserved]
date | location | id | quantity
```

and you have an input like

```
{
  date: '10/21/18',
  location: 1,
  request: [
    {
       id: 1,
       quantity: 3
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       quantity: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the most efficient way to run the following calculation for each request id and quantity, and return a single boolean representing if all are true:

```
limit = false 
if (daily_limit for date/location/id) 
  limit = daily_limit
else if (default_limit for date/location/id)
  limit = default_limit

if (limit) 
  return quantity + reserved.quantity <= limit
else 
  return true
```

Based on some similar questions, I was trying to join the tables by id and location and then COALESCE(daily_limit.limit, default_limit.limit) but I don't know how to factor the date into it, or handle the situation where neither exists, and the date/location/id combination is unlimited.

Currently I'm working it all out in application code, but I laid out the schema this way knowing that there has to be a savvy way to do it directly in SQL.

Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with this, quick and dirty

```
create table default_limit (id int,location int, "limit" int );
create table daily_limit (id int,location int, "limit" int, dt date );
create table reserved (id int,location int, quantity int, dt date );

insert into default_limit(id,location,"limit") values (1,1,5);
insert into default_limit(id,location,"limit") values (2,1,5);

insert into daily_limit(id,location,"limit",dt) values (1,1,3,'10/21/18'::DATE);

insert into reserved(id,location,quantity,dt) values (1,1,1,'10/21/18'::DATE);

create or replace function q(p_id int,p_location int,p_quantity int, p_dt date)
RETURNS boolean
as $$
select 
  coalesce(
  (p_quantity + coalesce(l3.quantity,0))
  <=
  coalesce(l2."limit",l1."limit",2147483647)
  ,true)
  from
  (select * from default_limit where id = p_id
                                 and location = p_location
                                 limit 1) l1
   full join 
   (select * from daily_limit where id = p_id
                                 and location = p_location
                                 and dt = p_dt
                                 limit 1) l2
   on true                              
   full join
   (select * from reserved where id = p_id
                                 and location = p_location
                                 and dt = p_dt
                                 limit 1) l3
   on true                              
   full join (select 1 as p) ph on true
$$ language sql;

select q(1,1,1,'10/21/18'); -- true
select q(1,1,2,'10/21/18'); -- true
select q(1,1,3,'10/21/18'); -- false


select q(3,4,42,'10/22/18'); -- true
```